# Removing Specific Prefix from String Vector in R

Tags: r, string

I need to be able to test if certain words appear at the start of a character vector. I've written a function which seems to work:

```
remove_from_front <- function(my_str, my_prefix) {
  
  remove_from_front <- ifelse(startsWith(my_str, my_prefix),
                              substr(my_str, nchar(my_prefix) + 1, nchar(my_str)),
                              my_str)
  
  remove_from_front
  
}

test_strings <- c("The Quick Brown Fox",
                  "The Quick Yellow Fox",
                  "The Slow Red Fox")

remove_from_front(test_strings, "The Quick ")
```

This looks for `"The Quick "` at the start of a string, and removes it if it finds it (and does nothing if it doesn't find it).

I'm wondering if there's some more concise way to do it using some existing R functionality - can anyone advise please?

Comment: `stringr::str_remove(test_strings, "^The Quick ")` adding the ^ the the start of the pattern means "only look at the beginning"

Comment: Ahhhhhh I think this works. The ^ is the key part here - I was unaware of this trick. Thank you. Much nicer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sub` to replace a pattern within a string in R. Use a `^` at the start of your match pattern so that only strings *starting with* this pattern are replaced. Just replace with the empty string, `""`

```r
sub("^The Quick ", "", test_strings)
#> [1] "Brown Fox"        "Yellow Fox"       "The Slow Red Fox"
```

Alternately, use `trimws`:

```r
trimws(test_strings, whitespace = '^The Quick ')
#> [1] "Brown Fox"        "Yellow Fox"       "The Slow Red Fox"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>